# I have a problem integrating stripepromise

Tags: stripe-payments

[image: IntegrationError: Missing value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string.]

I'm getting an error for my stripe key. It says
IntegrationError: Missing value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string.

Comment: Maybe `REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY` is not being set. Could you share how are you passing it? Another thing is that loadStripe returns a promise and you should await for its result. I'm not sure whether you're doing this by calling `await getStripe()` or what exactly.

Comment: Hi Tarzan. I had it in the .env file but changed it to passing it in direct as a string. I tried again with the publishable key and it worked. Not sure where I got the other wrong key from. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this. All you need to do is wrap the environment variable into template literal:

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}`);
```

That's it!